# unique constraint with a condition to accept multiple nulls on a unique column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, null, unique

I was wondering what would the proper way to have a Unique conditional constraint be?
So if a user enters nothing into the AccountIdentifier field and submit, it will show up as Null in the database, however because of the unique constraint, it can't have multiple nulls, is there a way to do this?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AccountTemplate]
(
    [AccountID] INT NOT NULL,
    [AccountIdentifier] NCHAR(50) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AccountTemplate_Identifier] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([AccountIdentifier] ASC, [AccountID] ASC)
)
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question

Comment: JamesZ answer is correct just beware though there are a couple of catches. The following sqlmag article describes this approach quit well:
http://sqlmag.com/blog/whats-good-use-unique-filtered-index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your index as filtered. If you leave out null values from the index, the uniqueness will not be enforced either.

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` is not a value, it's the lack thereof. You can have as many `NULL`s as you want in a unique column. See, e.g., this [sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fec0/1/0) with your table.